# How to remove decimal on smarty template

Tags: regex, decimal, smarty

I work on a project base on prestashop cms.

This cms use smarty and i need to modify a tpl file to display a price without decimal.

I just want to modify one tpl and not applying this trick to full website

I found in another thread a code to remove null decimals like this 51,00

```
convertPrice|regex_replace:'/[.,]0+/':''
```

But i don't know how to change this code to remove decimal decimals like this too: 51,85 transform to 51

Many thanks
R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the `0+` into `[0-9]+` or `\d+`. Both means any digits.

```
convertPrice|regex_replace:'/[.,][0-9]+/':''
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to round the number (ie. anything above 0.5 becomes 1), you can use the following to display the price:

```
{number_format($price, 0)}
```

Documentation here: [php.net/number_format](http://php.net/number_format)

Answer (score 1):

User number_format function without parameters.
Like this

```
  {$price|number_format}
```